# Entity Framework 4.4 SaveChanges Exclude Related Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EntityFramework.dll version 4.4 with .NET 4.0.  I have an entity that's contains a reference to another entity like the following:

```
[Table("Bar")]
public class Bar
{
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public Foo Foo { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey("Foo")]
  public string FooId {get; set; }
}
```

When I want to add a new "Bar" record to the database, EntityFramework tries to also add an instance of "Foo", but I don't want it to do this.  **Is there a way to tell EF to ignore the Foo entity when Bar is created?**  I *do not* want to set [NotMapped] on Foo because it does need to be mapped - it's just that I don't want it to save.  So I'd like for the following to work:

```
public void CreateBar(Bar b)
{
   _barContext.Bars.Add(b);
   // This function doesn't exist, but I would like it to exist
   _barContext.Exclude("Foo");
   _barContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Not sure of the answer, but as a start you will need to make FooId nullable.

Comment: How do you know that *'EntityFramework tries to also add an instance of "Foo"'*?

Comment: @haim770, I'm using EF Profiler, and I also get a unique key violation in the Foo table.  Because it's trying to insert a Foo that already exists.

Comment: Thinking about this, are you sure the two entities are the correct way around. IE If a Foo always has a Bar, but a Bar may or may not have a Foo, should be the foreign key be BarId in the Foo entity with a virtual Foo within Bar.

Comment: Save a reference to foo set the foo to null save you bar and reset the foo property to your previously saved reference, or you could manually reset the entity state to unchanged/detached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the NotMapped attribute, see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I understand that that would work, but I asked for a solution that doesn't involve using NotMapped if possible.  I still need the Foo entity to be mapped for other usages of the Bar entity.  Thanks for your reply though.

Comment: You won't be able to sometimes have it as required and sometimes not. Not by using one model and one DB.  The property in the DB will be set as not nullable, and setup with referential integrity. Only way to have it bothways is marking it as Nullable, and ensuring the property gets set when it needs to.

Comment: I had originally had the ForeignKey attribute on Bar's "Foo" property.  But when I removed that attribute and instead moved it to the Foo entity, I was able to add "NotMapped" attribute to Bar's "Foo" property and everything works now.  Thanks for the help!